# Why this is not working with AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper

I'm new in AutoMapper and I'm trying to map list to list in this way:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<List<Person>, List<PersonMin>>();
});
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
List<Person> source = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Davis", Address = "Street1", Age = 40},
    new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Rob", LastName = "Mavis", Address = "Street2", Age = 42}
};
List<PersonMin> destination = iMapper.Map<List<Person>, List<PersonMin>>(source);
foreach (var item in destination)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id + ", " + item.FirstName + ", " + item.LastName);
}
```

The destination is empty.

Comment: You need a map for Person, the list is handled by default.

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: :) ```cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonMin>();```

Comment: I know that. I've meant on part after that, that is how to reference the lists of objects?

Comment: I see. The part after that is the same as I wrote. Thanks.

Comment: Please, write you answer as normal one and I'll check it as right answer to my question.

Comment: It's ok. If you want, write an answer that might help the next guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to care about the list.

Just simply map the models

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonMin>();
});
```